# 2X Daily Copy of SQL Data from one server to another (500mb) - what is best practice?

Tags: sql-server

We want to move data (500MB) in a SQL table on server 'A' to server 'B' twice a day. The data in the destination can be deleted each time and repopulated. The destination table is one table as is the source.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  It is a job that runs BCP? I would like the push to go to a view to allow future changes to the back end table structure if needed. Does this make sense?

Both servers are Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Thank you.

Comment: Can you enable change tracking on the "other" server? This would allow you to find all changes that occured since the last time you exported the data

Comment: 'Change tracking' sounds like the way to go.  Then getting BCP to transfer only the changes. This seems to fit the situation best.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would attempt is a `MERGE` executed on the target server pulling from the source server as a linked server. You can write the merge so that it fully updates the target table, but it will only perform writes when actual changes have been made. Should be fast if the delta is small.

Comment: That sounds great but we are not allowed to 'Link' servers here... :(

Comment: @usr MERGE has to join the two tables to find the differences. With a linked server, that means that either all the required data has to be transferred to one of the two servers, or that one query will be executed per row on the remote server. Worse, a distributed transaction would be forced on both servers. This would end up being very slow

Comment: Faster than BCP, @PanagiotisKanavos, which also has to copy all data. Normally, such a MERGE executed at the target results in a super fast merge join on pre-sorted inputs. Querying 500MB from a table is quite cheap. Takes a few seconds.

Comment: BCP doesn't have to copy all data. In fact, there *are* techniques that allow extracting only the changed data, like Change Tracking, available in all SQL Server editions. Moreover, BCP is a lot faster than MERGE even if the entire database is transferred, because it doesn't require continued communication between the servers, can load data as fast as they can be read from disk *and* requires minimal logging - generating log records per modified page rather than per row.

Comment: BCP will always be slower than select * from T because it does just that plus additional things. Bulk insert using insert.select is minimal logging capable. Transferring changes can be arbitrarily faster but requires, by far, more effort. Like 10x.

Comment: Anyway, this answer is dead because linked servers are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If linking servers is not an option for security reasons, you might want to look at this article: [Web Synchronization for Merge Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763%28v=sql.110%29) Excerpts from there:

> **How Web Synchronization Works**
>
> The Merge Agent is started at the Subscriber. The agent does the
>   following:
>         Makes an SQL connection to the subscription database.
>         Extracts any changes from the database.
>         Makes an HTTPS request to the computer that is running IIS.
>         Uploads data changes as an XML message.
>         The SQL Server Replication Listener and Merge Replication Reconciler that are hosted on the computer that is running IIS do the 
>   following:
>         Respond to the HTTPS request.
>         Make an SQL connection to the publication database.
>         Apply the upload changes to the publication database.
>         Extract the download changes for the Subscriber.
>         Send an HTTPS response back to the Merge Agent.    The Merge Agent at the Subscriber then accepts the HTTPS response and applies 
>   the download changes to the subscription database.

Needless to say, both services can be configured to run on one IIS server.

Comment: That is an interesting solution. Thank you for the input.